# How can I notify the user when I sent the message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Does anyone know the code to make the popup chat window. How can I notify the user when I sent the message? How can I get the user's window focused? Or blinking the pop up window. Currently I have this code:

```
function stateChangeHandler() {
    //readyState of 4 or 'complete' represents that data has been returned 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 'complete') {
        //Gather the results from the callback 
        var str = xmlHttp.responseText;
        if (str != "") {  
            var chatmsgs = eval(str);
            for (ind = 0; ind < chatmsgs.length; ind++) {
                var senderId = chatmsgs[ind].Sender;
                var chatId = chatmsgs[ind].ChatId;
                var message = chatmsgs[ind].Msg;
                var msgId = chatmsgs[ind].MsgId;

                message = restoreHtmlTags(message);
                document.getElementById('msgPanel').innerHTML += "<br><b>" + senderId + ": </b>" + message;
                MessageReceived(msgId, msgCounter);

                document.getElementById('msgPanel').scrollTop = document.getElementById('msgPanel').scrollHeight;
                window.focus();             

           }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working only in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I use below JS file for popup which is very neat and simple.

http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

At the bottom of page add two divs like

```
<div id="popupContact" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"></div>
```

On Server side do code like this

```
popupContact.innerHTML = "your message";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "open", "centerPopup();loadPopup();", true);
```

You can call these from page itself. it is small JS and CSS files though.